# Positioning footer logo

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-position, footer

So I want to add a logo in the footer. It needs be right besides the text on its left side.

```
<div class="siteFooterBar">
    <div class="content">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/nuRmQJX.png" width="70px" height="70px" align="left">
            <div class="foot">2014 © All rights reserved.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using `margin-left`/`margin-right` for both does solve it as different resolutions will render the fixed length differently. Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5c7DY/1/) and a [graphical example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSNmX.png) of what I want to achieve.

What's the best approach towards this? Would it be *practical* if I used % with `margin-left`/`margin-right`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take align="left" from the image as so:

```
<div class="siteFooterBar">
    <div class="content">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/nuRmQJX.png" width="70px" height="70px">
            <div class="foot">2014 © All rights reserved.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Than add some css:

```
.foot { display: inline-block; line-height: 70px; vertical-align: top }

.img { display: inline-block;  }
```

And the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5c7DY/5/)

Comment: I was just about to submit an answer as I achieved it in a bit of a different way: `.foot {display: inline-block;}
img {vertical-align: middle;}`. Anyway, thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="siteFooterBar">
        <div class="content">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/nuRmQJX.png" >
                <div class="foot">2014 © All rights reserved.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.siteFooterBar {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgb(207, 207, 207);
    height: 78px;
    color: #9B9B9B;
    background: #F3F3F3;
}

.content {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    font: 25px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    width:250px;
}
.foot {
 display:inline;
    line-height: 70px;
}
.content img {
 height:70px;
    width: 70px;
    float:left;
}
```

URL:
http://jsfiddle.net/5c7DY/6/

Enjoy your code!

Comment: Also a valid answer. One up from me.

Comment: Another one from me. Thanks for the answer :)